# Implicit is ambiguous when scalac chooses between Map[K,V] and Traversable[T]

Tags: scala, implicit

While extending MongoDB serialization library I stumbled upon issue with implicits.

In sample project referred below scalac fails to choose between implicits for `Map[K,V]` and `Traversable[T]`. The warning I get after enabling logging is

```
[info] ambiguous implicit values:
[info]  both method mapSetterStringKey in object BsonWritable of type [V](implicit vw: com.osinka.subset.BsonWritable[V])com.osinka.subset.BsonWritable[Map[String,V]]
[info]  and method seqSetter in object BsonWritable of type [T](implicit w: com.osinka.subset.BsonWritable[T])com.osinka.subset.BsonWritable[Traversable[T]]
[info]  match expected type com.osinka.subset.BsonWritable[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[Double]]]
[info]     val bson = DBO(name -> testMap)()
[info]                         ^
```

If you uncomment marshallers in object `BsonMarshallers` it works. But it fails when both implicits are specified in `com.osinka.subset.BsonWritable`.

Could you please explain why scalac doesn't choose more specific implicit for `Map` ?

https://github.com/cppexpert/subset2-implicit-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, this bit from [Programming in Scala, First Edition](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/implicit-conversions-and-parameters.html) might explain it.

> Non-Ambiguity Rule: An implicit conversion is only inserted if there
>   is no other possible conversion to insert. If the compiler has two
>   options to fix x + y, say using either convert1(x) + y or convert2(x)
>   + y, then it will report an error and refuse to choose between them. It would be possible to define some kind of "best match" rule that
>   prefers some conversions over others. However, such choices lead to
>   really obscure code. Imagine the compiler chooses convert2, but you
>   are new to the file and are only aware of convert1—you could spend a
>   lot of time thinking a different conversion had been applied!
>
> In cases like this, one option is to remove one of the imported
>   implicits so that the ambiguity is removed. If you prefer convert2,
>   then remove the import of convert1. Alternatively, you can write your
>   desired conversion explicitly: convert2(x) + y.